# Number of "possible" rational roots of a univariate polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, roots

Is it possible to determine the number of possible rational roots of a single variable polynomial?

```
    polynomial a0 + a1x + a2x^2 + ... + anx^n.
```

This is to find all integers p that is a factor of a0 and for all integers q that is a factor of an, check if the rational number p/q is a root for the input polynomial.

I thought of simply multiplying the number of factors of `a0` and `an`, but wouldn't the possibility of duplicates exist?

I need it to create a program that will get the rational roots. Thanks :)

Comment: Did you take a look at the rational root theorem ?

Comment: Your second paragraph describes how to determine this number. Is there something you don't understand about this argument?

Comment: How do I remove the duplicates from the count? Like when dealing with 8 and 4. 8/4 is 2, and 4/2 is also 2. Wouldn't just multiplying the number of factors include two 2s in the count?

Comment: Just remove those combination whose gcd $\ne 1$, e.g. 
$$8/4 \to \begin{cases}
8/4,\, 4/4,\, 2/4,\, 1/4 &\to 1/4,\\
8/2,\, 4/2,\, 2/2,\, 1/2 &\to 1/2,\\
8/1,\, 4/1,\, 2/1,\, 1/1 &\to 8, 4, 2, 1
\end{cases}$$
As one can see, all possible exponent of $2$ is covered at least once
(with at least one of the factors from $p$ and $q$ is $1$). The check gcd $\ne 1$ removes the duplication.

Comment: Can you give me another example? Thanks :D

Comment: I don't quite understand how 8/4 -> 1/4 happened. Sorry.

Comment: Removing the duplicate is more a programming question than a math question. You can find a list of rational roots and then remove in your list the duplicate of the rational having different representations.